# Why can I 'touch' a write-protected file?

Tags: linux, permissions, touch

Why is it possible to `touch` a write-protected file?

Shouldn't the following give an error?

```
$ touch test.txt
$ chmod a-w test.txt
$ ls -l test.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 name group 0 Jun 13 09:14 test.txt
$ touch test.txt && echo OK
OK
$ ls -l test.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 name group 0 Jun 13 09:15 test.txt
```

Does `touch` change permissions, touch the file, and change permissions back? Why would it do that?

Given this behavior, if I really want to protect a file so that I (my user) will never (unintentionally) change, remove or change its timestamp in the future -- how can I do it?

(Sorry, not strictly programming-related, but slightly, and probably of interest to many programmers.)

Comment: Sounds like a question more suited for serverfault.com in my oppinion.

Comment: Does the timestamp change when you do that?

Comment: Yes. Added the changed timestamp above.

Answer (score 6):

From the `touch` (coreutils) documentation:

> If changing both the access and
>   modification times to the current
>   time, `touch' can change the
>   timestamps for files that the user
>   running it does not own but has write
>   permission for. Otherwise, the user
>   must own the files.

Comment: That only seems to cover ownership - the question was about write access so I believe @objlass has it right - timestamps are held in the directory entry, not the file, so write access to the directory is enough to change them.

Comment: That could be a little clearer. Is it saying that if you can `touch` files with either w-perms *or* ownership?

Comment: Yes, with either of those, given that the user has +W on the directory

Answer (score 6):

The execution permissions of the directory that the file contains dictates the ability to delete or modify the inode information for the entry in the directory that is associated with the file.

As the comment below indicates I have glossed over the technical reason but instead offered a reasoning why the behavior might not be as expected.  Since you can execute in the directory there are a number of things you can do to tinker with the file and I am going to leave it at that.

If you want to stop anyone but root from modifying a file the best method is to use the chattr +i filename on the file.  Even root will not be able to perform any actions on it without running chattr -i on it.  This applies to Linux so YMMV.

Comment: Could the user touch readonly files that are owned by someone else if said user has execute permissions on the directory?

Comment: You can delete a file that you cannot read in a directory where you have execute permission.  There can be a lot of experimentation and variations done but the fact remains permissions of files are not the definitive end all be all indication of the actions you are authorized to perform.

Comment: Execute permission on the directory is required in order to specify a file name in the directory, but that alone does not permit "touch".  For "touch", you must be the owner of the file (as here), or have write permission, or be root.

Comment: -1 misinformation. Execute on a directory controls traversal/cd/search, not delete/modify permissions for the file inodes. That is determined by the Write permission on the directory. The OP never bothered to specify his directory permissions. This behaviour implies that the directory had +w for him.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the relevant output from : strace "touch test.txt"

```
open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
futimesat(AT_FDCWD, "test.txt", NULL)   = 0
```

It indeed gets a "Permission denied error" on the [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) system call regarding  EACCES. See relevant section in [utimes(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/utimes) man page.

However, it does succeed in updating the timestamp using the [futimesat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/futimesat) system call.

As others have indicated, it looks like the directory permissions hold the rights to update access/moficiation timestamps.

You can, however change the attribute of a file to immutable using:

```
chattr +i test.txt
```

Note: Only root can do this, and it's a very harsh way to disable access to files. But in extreme cases, it can be useful. In addition, this is an ext2/3/4 feature, not available on other filesystems as far as I know.

Comment: You beat me to it Tom, "not programming related" my hat :) OP might like to check the EACCES paragraph in the man page for utimes(2) or futimesat(2), not to mention the souce for touch(1).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I added the utimes(2) link to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can update the modification time if you own the file, regardless of write permission.  (It is not related to any permission on the directory.)

From POSIX.1-2008:

> Only a process with the effective user ID equal to the user ID of the file, or with write access to the file, or with appropriate privileges may use `futimens()` or `utimensat()` with a null pointer as the times argument or with both `tv_nsec` fields set to the special value `UTIME_NOW`. Only a process with the effective user ID equal to the user ID of the file or with appropriate privileges may use `futimens()` or `utimensat()` with a non-null times argument that does not have both `tv_nsec` fields set to `UTIME_NOW` and does not have both `tv_nsec` fields set to `UTIME_OMIT`. If both `tv_nsec` fields are set to `UTIME_OMIT`, no ownership or permissions check shall be performed for the file, but other error conditions may still be detected (including [EACCES] errors related to the path prefix).

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms, using the touch command will update or create a file without editing/modifying its contents. Because the command doesn't(and can't) write or erase anything from the file, it can be used on write-protected files. See the wiki on the touch command for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)